# file_get_contents("php://input") is empty

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

I'm using `file_get_contents("php://input")` to get the body of a post request. However, it's coming back as an empty string when I call var_dump(). I checked php.ini config and `allow_url_fopen` is set to On.

I'm using postman to test the request. Nothing special, no multipart/form, just a plain post with a few params. Because I'm using php://input always_populate_raw_post_data can be configured off, right?

Comment: yes, `always_populate_raw_post_data` can configured off. You have to post more code or/and details. As per your description, your code has not problem.

Comment: Try enabling `error_reporting` and `dispaly_errors` and check if it's throwing any errors

Comment: There is no more code that really matters. At the very top of my php script there's <code>var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"))</code> Then I just make a request using postman. The script is definitely getting hit and producing 200 ok it's just there's an empty string even though I'm passing params in url param key : value

Comment: show how do you posting your data (headers, params)

Comment: sending this post request in postman: http://www.beanbagapp.com/beanbag/flagContent.php?name=Bill&userName=bpp123

Comment: the code looks like: $JSONArray  = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); var_dump($JSONArray)

Comment: Content-Type → text/html; charset=utf-8

Answer (score -1):

if you already asigned the value, eg $str = file_get_contents("php://input"); then when you var_dump it would go for empty.

Using postman (Chrome Extension) to check your post value.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need enable `always_populate_raw_post_data`

Reference [here](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.always-populate-raw-post-data)

Comment: No. `always_populate_raw_post_data` refer to `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`. Read careful your own link.